# Opencv CalibrateCamera - Error

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to calibrate camera using opencv in python, but im' getting this error. I've printed all the variables here, and there is no problem, but for some reason i'm getting this error. 'ret' is true meaning the pattern is found.

[image: Calibrate camera error]

Comment: Please, don't post code and error messages as an image -- this way it can't be searched, can't be copied and pasted into a text editor, it won't work with a screen reader, etc.

Comment: Hi dan, thankyou, i'll make sure i post text in future. And I identified the issue for this...I didn't change the shape in the `objp = np.zeros((8*6, 3), np.float32)` It was 9*6 originally. Thankyou! And how do i close this question?